# Accessing DOL State Unemployment Insurance Weekly Claims Data

Tags: api, labor, python, odata

I would like to access weekly data for unemployment claims through the DOL API (Department of Labor), listed here: https://oui.doleta.gov/unemploy/claims.asp

I'm able to get national data by using the pydol ([https://pypi.org/project/pydol](https://pypi.org/project/pydol/)) interface but I'm not sure how to get it on the state level.

I appreciate all your help!